# MVC3 - Where is UserId and Roles information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, class-design

This is the Model code generated in MVC3 for Account/Membership class for a sample project I created. I do not see UserId field/attribute or Roles information..
Where is the UserId and Roles information ?

```
  public class ChangePasswordModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Current password")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

public class LogOnModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Unless i'm misunderstanding the question...

Those models are concerned with the User **model**.

UserId and Roles are dealing with **authentication and authorization**.

Most likely, you are using Forms Authentication and the default ASP.NET Membership provider.

If you want to access the UserId of the current logged in user, you need to add it to the forms authentication ticket when you sign the user in, then you can access it via `HttpContext.Current.Request.User.Identity`.

If your using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`, then `Identity.Name` will point to whatever you passed to `SetAuthCookie` - so you could pass the UserId.

But most people (myself included), use nicknames/usernames for the `Identity.Name`, so you need to create the Forms Authentication ticket manually and add it to the response cookies.

To see if a user is in a role, do this:

`HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrator")`

This is standard ASP.NET stuff, not specific to ASP.NET MVC.

Also, if your using an ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate or Linq2Sql, don't map the membership tables.

Create your own User table which has a FK pointing to that table, then your User table becomes the model.

The built in membership provider API will use stored procedures behind the scenes to perform the functionality you require.

Answer (score 0):

This is a models for default views - register and change password.

Role can be taken only if roleprovider is configured.

Comment: Roles are configured via "Asp.net configuration" website. +

Comment: I guess what I am asking is - If I am writing other models for other views and want to use the userid of the user logged in, how can I use it when userId does not exist in the account model?

Comment: You can create account model. These models you've shown are only for simple example. Here is a good post how to use IPrincipal object: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IPrincipalUserModelBinderInASPNETMVCForEasierTesting.aspx

Comment: This is using standard membership ASPNETDB.MDF database. The userid field already exists in that database. Why do I have to create a model again to make use of UserId? Sorry if my question is elementary in nature.. I am a beginner

Comment: To store user membership and role in SQL database use aspnet_regsql.exe application or configurator page. The default template does not contains models for retrieving user id or smth. Just use standard IPrincipal object to get access to this fieds.