# Where is data persisted when using Membership.CreateUser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a .NET MVC 3, razor site and I want to know where data is persisted when using Membership.CreateUser?

On http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8t4h2es.aspx it says:

> CreateUser adds a new user to the data store and returns a MembershipUser object for the newly created user.

Which data store is that? The local .sdf file in App data does not have any tables for user credentials?

Also feel free to provide some good links on helping me understand the .NET MVC3 security model.

Comment: Have you checked your web.config?

Comment: FYI: this is similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363129/mvc3-where-is-userid-and-roles-information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, it uses a store in App_Data, creating an ASPNETDB.mdf file, at least in web forms.  The behaviour would be the same for MVC, with the exception of the creating the DB automatically part.  You can use the aspnet_regiis tools to generate the tables it needs in any SQL database, or roll your own provider, and update the membership registration in the `<system.web><membership>` element as you did in web forms..

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a membership database.

If this doesn't exist you can do it manually by following the steps on [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/10/02/installing-asp-net-membership-services-database-in-sql-server-expreess.aspx)

You need to run the [`aspnet_regsql.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=VS.100).aspx) utility and follow the steps in the wizard. This will create the various tables you need.

[More information from the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)

> ASP.NET membership gives you a built-in way to validate and store user credentials.
>
> The default provider stores membership information in a Microsoft SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the bundled security model in ASP.NET MVC 1.0 and 2.0 based on [ASP.NET Membership API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx).So there is no special security API for ASP.NET MVC itself. it is based on existing ASP.NET Membership

And when you install membership you are creating custom tables and stored procs. So The user you mentioned should be stored on SQL Database.

From [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/10/02/installing-asp-net-membership-services-database-in-sql-server-expreess.aspx) link you can see after the installation there shold be **aspnet_users** table which is users stored.

I dont know if there is a security API for ASP.NET MVC 3.0 because I have removed ASP.NET Membership classes shipped with ASP.NET MVC long time ago and I have implemented myself.

Also I strongly recommed to remove ASP.NET MVC membership classes if **User** has a special meaning and has other properties other than just a username/password in your problem domain.

Comment: Just did some more research and found out it is stored in the ASPNETDB.MDF file that gets automatically created in the App_Data folder.

Answer (score 0):

when setting up your membership provider you will run a regsql command that will create the schema in your data store (whatever store you are using) and put the connection string in your web.config.  You could use any datastore that .Net has a provider for (ORACLE, MYSql, SQLite, SQL Server, MS Access, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can still interact with the built-in MS Membership classes and functions from your MVC project using something like the MvcMembership starter Kit DLL's.

https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit

Hope this helps!